# Make view pages searchable

Tags: search

I have created some views to list specific content types. Is it possible to make the view page searchable?

To solve the issue, I have tried installing the Search API module, but nothing appears to solve the issue.

Comment: Yep, index the content that the View displays, setting up field weights as appropriate for your needs. That'll have the same effect as raw-indexing a rendered Views page.

Comment: eg: We list industries on a view page. Title is industries. When searched for industries this view page should be displayed.

Comment: If you are searching the site, no, a Views page is not indexed and is not a search result.

Comment: Is there any way to index Views page.

Comment: No. It isn't very practical. You basically would have to redo it and use a views block on a node instead of create a views page.